# JPA + JSP - Erro ao tentar inserir informações no banco de dados

Tags: java, jpa, jsp

Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver. estou tentando inserir as informações no banco e não estou conseguindo. o navegador está retornando o seguinte erro ao cadastrar.
Served at: /SISTEMA_ESCOLAR

Segue meu código.

> Classe *ServletCadastrousuario*

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.cleiton.cadastro.Usuario;
import com.cleiton.topicos2.SalvarUsuario;

@WebServlet("/salvarusuario")
public class ServletCadastrousuario extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     private SalvarUsuario salvarUsuario = new com.cleiton.topicos2.SalvarUsuario();

    public ServletCadastrousuario() {
        super();

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String nome = request.getParameter("inputNome");
        String cpf = request.getParameter("inputCPF");
        String email = request.getParameter("inpuEmail");
        String senha = request.getParameter("senha");
        String telresidencial = request.getParameter("inputResidencial");
        String celular = request.getParameter("inputCelular");
        String cep = request.getParameter("inputCEP");
        String numero = request.getParameter("inputNumero");
        String logradouro = request.getParameter("inputLogradouro");
        String bairro = request.getParameter("inputBairro");
        String localidade = request.getParameter("inputLocalidade");
        String estado = request.getParameter("inputEstado");


        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        usuario.setUSR_NOME(nome);
        usuario.setUSR_CPF(cpf);
        usuario.setUSR_EMAIL(email);
        usuario.setUSR_SENHA(senha);
        usuario.setUSR_TELEFONE(telresidencial);
        usuario.setUSR_CELULAR(celular);
        usuario.setUSR_CEP(cep);
        usuario.setUSR_NUMERO(numero);
        usuario.setUSR_LOGRADOURO(logradouro);
        usuario.setUSR_BAIRRO(bairro);
        usuario.setUSR_LOCALIDADE(localidade);
        usuario.setUSR_ESTADO(estado);



        salvarUsuario.salvar(usuario);

    }

}
```

> Classe *SalvarUsuario*

```
package com.cleiton.topicos2;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import com.cleiton.cadastro.Usuario;

public class SalvarUsuario {
    public void salvar(Usuario ServletCadastrousuario){

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("teste");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Usuario CADASTRO_USUARIO = new Usuario();


        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_NOME(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_NOME());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_CPF(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_CPF());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_EMAIL(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_EMAIL());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_SENHA(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_SENHA());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_TELEFONE(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_TELEFONE());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_CELULAR(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_CELULAR());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_CEP(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_CEP());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_NUMERO(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_NUMERO());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_LOGRADOURO(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_LOGRADOURO());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_BAIRRO(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_BAIRRO());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_LOCALIDADE(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_LOCALIDADE());
        CADASTRO_USUARIO.setUSR_ESTADO(ServletCadastrousuario.getUSR_ESTADO());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(CADASTRO_USUARIO);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        //em.close();
        System.out.println("usuário salvo com sucesso!!");
    }
}
```

---

fiz a mudança porém está dando o seguinte erro.

```
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SISTEMA_ESCOLAR' did not find a matching property.
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Mar 28 2017 16:01:48 UTC
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         7.0.77.0
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 7
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            6.1
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\wtpwebapps
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\endorsed
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\eclipse;;.
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 989 ms
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service Catalina
out 30, 2017 7:12:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.77
out 30, 2017 7:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 30, 2017 7:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMAÇÕES: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [219] milliseconds.
out 30, 2017 7:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\docs
out 30, 2017 7:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 30, 2017 7:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\docs has finished in 96 ms
out 30, 2017 7:12:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\examples
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@30032c0d')
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\examples has finished in 561 ms
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\host-manager
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\host-manager has finished in 98 ms
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\manager
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\manager has finished in 86 ms
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\ROOT
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\ROOT has finished in 79 ms
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
out 30, 2017 7:13:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 2113 ms
out 30, 2017 7:14:28 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: teste
    ...]
out 30, 2017 7:14:28 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
out 30, 2017 7:14:28 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
out 30, 2017 7:14:28 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
out 30, 2017 7:14:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
out 30, 2017 7:14:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.ServletCadastrousuario] in context with path [/SISTEMA_ESCOLAR] threw exception
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.cleiton.topicos2.SalvarUsuario.salvar(SalvarUsuario.java:10)
    at servlet.ServletCadastrousuario.doPost(ServletCadastrousuario.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345)
    ... 49 more

out 30, 2017 7:16:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMAÇÕES: Reloading Context with name [/SISTEMA_ESCOLAR] has started
out 30, 2017 7:16:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
out 30, 2017 7:16:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMAÇÕES: Reloading Context with name [/SISTEMA_ESCOLAR] is completed
```

Comment: Acredito que essa seja a saída correta do seu Servlet para Uma requisição do tipo *get*. Você precisa criar uma requisição *post* (e.g., um formulário que envie a requisição para o Servlet).

Comment: fiz isso porém está dando o seguinte erro.

Comment: Tem certeza que a conexão com o banco de dados está ok? Já testou uma consulta para ver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo seu log de erro, `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

o tomcat não consegue encontrar o drive do mysql.

Se estiver utilizando maven para gerenciar dependências:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Caso não esteja utilizando o maven, coloque o conector do mysql dentro da pasta **WEB-INF/lib** e verifique se está adicionado ao build path do seu projeto.